# Redis alternative with customized expiration time for Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis, jvm

I am looking to find a memory cache that will run on same jvm (not a separate service like redis), but provide customized expiration time for each entries.

Whenever I am adding any key value to cache, I will set expiration time.

The Solution will automatically envict that key value pair based on expiration time

Is there any framework exist with this capabilities?

Comment: So you want your memory cache to be the same JVM as your Spring Boot app, correct?  Also: look here: https://dzone.com/articles/be-careful-cache-managers

Comment: yes, but  the capability of individual entry expiration